# Horizontal Menu IE7 and IE8 compatibility Issue

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I created a horizontal menu which works perfectly in Firefox 6, IE9, Safari, Chrome and Opera but in IE7 & IE8 the last link in the menu breaks to the next line, I'm attaching the screenshot of the menu.

IE9 Screenshot of the Horizontal Menu
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/819/ie9screenshot.jpg/

IE8 Screenshot of the Horizontal Menu

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/696/ie8screenshot.jpg/

The HTML and CSS code are as follows:-

HTML Code:-

```
<ul class="menu">

        <li class="first"><a href="#">Bridal</a></li>

        <li><img src="images/divider.jpg" alt="Divider" /></li>

        <li><a href="#">Bridesmaid</a></li>

        <li><img src="images/divider.jpg" alt="Divider" /></li>

        <li><a href="#">Gentleman's</a></li>

        <li><img src="images/divider.jpg" alt="Divider" /></li>

        <li><a href="#">Flower Girl</a></li>

        <li><img src="images/divider.jpg" alt="Divider" /></li>

        <li><a href="#">Special Occassion</a></li>

        <li><img src="images/divider.jpg" alt="Divider" /></li>

        <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>

        <li><img src="images/divider.jpg" alt="Divider" /></li>

        <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>

        <li><img src="images/divider.jpg" alt="Divider" /></li>

        <li class="last"><a href="#">Sale</a></li>

    </ul> <!-- END OF MENU -->
```

CSS Code:-

```
ul.menu {
width: 965px;
height: 44px;
font-size: 18px;
color: #ffffff;
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

ul.menu li {
float: left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

ul.menu li a {
height: 34px;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
display: block;
background-image: url(images/menu-normal.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px 17px 0px 17px;
}

ul.menu li.first {
background: none;
}

ul.menu li.first a {
width: 88px;
background-image: url(images/first-normal.png);
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px 0px 0px 8px;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
background-image: url(images/menu-hover.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

ul.menu li.first a:hover {
background-image: url(images/first-hover.png);
}

ul.menu li.last a {
width: 68px;
background-image: url(images/last-normal.png);
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px 8px 0px 0px;
}

ul.menu li.last a:hover {
width: 68px;
background-image: url(images/last-hover.png);
}
```

I found some similar articles in this and other forums but none of them were helpful. I tried list-position: inside; display: inline; etc but none of them work. One more detail I'm viewing the html page in IE9 browser but checking them in IE7 and IE8 compatibility mode.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Can you give some online version link:)?

Comment: Hi lord_t, sorry I don't have the url of the website, I just do the psd to html work and send it to my client who does the uploads and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it seems that IE like to add invisible margins and padding so you might want to give your menu a bit more width and fix the position afterwards, I suggest using another css file for IE.

Comment: Thanks for the help Narvath, since this seemed like a minor issue I didn't feel like applying browser specific styles. I just wanted to know if there was any hidden css property which will overwrite the IE7 and IE8 bug (like the border-collapse to fix the table issues in IE7 and IE8).